# Wpf Material Design Date-Picker Theme

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

I can successfully build the date picker with the code below.

```
<Button  x:Name="ButtonOpenDialog" Content="..." IsEnabled="True" 
            Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=PopupAddCustom}"/>
<materialDesign:DialogHost Name="PopupAddCustom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsOpen="False"
            materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogOpenedCallback="CalendarDialogOpenedEventHandler"
            materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogClosingCallback="CalendarDialogClosingEventHandler">
    <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-2,0,2">
                <Calendar x:Name="MaterialCalendar" Margin="-1 -4 -1 0" IsTodayHighlighted="False" SelectedDatesChanged="MaterialCalendar_SelectedDatesChanged"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}" IsDefault="True" Margin="20 0"
            CommandParameter="1" >OK</Button>
                <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}" IsCancel="True"
            CommandParameter="0" >CANCEL</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

But I want to change foreground color and background color.As shown:

[image]

- Header Background Color To => Gray
- Header Text Foreground Color To => White
- Icon Color To => White
- Month Text Foreground Color To => White
- Main Background Color To => Black
- Main TextForeColor To => White

How can I do that? Is it possible to change without changing original source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `Background` property of the `Calendar` to `Black` and override two resources:

```
<Calendar x:Name="MaterialCalendar" Margin="-1 -4 -1 0" 
          IsTodayHighlighted="False"
          Background="Black">
    <Calendar.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="Gray" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignBody" Color="White" />
    </Calendar.Resources>
</Calendar>
```